# Xcode: set image on button only for default state, not also selected

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, selected

I am new to Xcode and iPhone programming in general.. I have a simple problem thats bugging me.. I want to set an image on a button, for it's default state. So I select the button, and in the "Show the attributes inspector"-tab, I select "state config" to be default, then I find the desired image in "image"-drop down list...

**Problem:**

I change the "state config" to selected, and the image is still on. I need the image to only be on in default state. I have same problem if i want different font size of the title text in default- and selected-state.
I'm using Xcode 4.6 and writing for iOS 6.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways.

First way, programmatically:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonimg forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonimg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:buttonimg forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Second way, using IB Builder:

Like the img:

[image]

You have a option of selecting a state config. Based on the config, you can set the image under the section called "Image".

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do that programatically? It will be much simpler.

```
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:cancelImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cancelButton setBackgroundImage:selectedImg forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programmatically the answer of akash is the way to go. 
But if you want to do so from interface builder you should follow these 2 steps (image here: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s29/sh/9abb1987-614d-4326-b5bb-bcff28756ee4/85d6ca236276166992ff01a082222e96):

1. for each *State Config*
2. select the image you want or left it empty

Xcode put the same image you add for the *Default* state in the *Selected* state but if you change the second it will not be overwritten automatically.