# Disabled buttons not changing image in

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, viewwillappear, uicontrolstate

I have a button that pushes to a settings `viewController`. On that settings `viewController` I has a switch to invert all the colors on the original view, an inversion which I've done programmatically. I made inverted button images to replace the original images.

When I return to the original view, I have `viewWillAppear` call the method to invert if the switch has been flipped. Everything changes accordingly except for two disabled buttons.

The switch value is saved under the default settings so that the user can exit the app and come back later and still have the colors inverted. When `viewDidLoad` calls the invert method, the buttons change just fine, and they even show up adjusted to show they are disabled.

Any idea what might be going on?

```
-(void)invert{

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

//Buttons
[self.stopButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stopinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    _inverted = 
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"isInvertedOn"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    if(_inverted){
        [self invert];
    } else {
        [self unInvert];
    }
    [super viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that the image is not updated automatically, you'll need to reset the `enabled` value to make it work:

```
[self.stopButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stopinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.stopButton.enabled = ! self.stopButton.enabled;
self.stopButton.enabled = ! self.stopButton.enabled;

[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.playButton.enabled = ! self.playButton.enabled;
self.playButton.enabled = ! self.playButton.enabled;
```

Comment: Indeed. This is a bug introduced with iOS 7. If you set the image while the button is disabled. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are disabling **stopButton** and **playButton** before applying the image. And also you are applying `UIImage` for `UIButton` normal `UIControlState`. I would suggest do the following code changes

Change this

```
//Buttons
[self.stopButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stopinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

to

```
//Buttons
[self.stopButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stopinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateDisabled];        
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playinverted"]
                 forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

In short you have to set `UIButton` `UIImages` in disabled state.

For more reference have a look this questions answer [Xcode: set image on button only for default state, not also selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108754/xcode-set-image-on-button-only-for-default-state-not-also-selected)

If you set the `UIImages` according to the state of the `UIButton` then in the function in which you want to invert the `UIImage`, you have to only need to handle the state of the `UIButton` and it will automatically change the image.

Comment: playinverted image should be for state UIControlStateNormal not UIControlStateDisabled.

Comment: Yes @pawan.its MScottWaller choice which image he has to apply and where. Our task is to guide him.

Comment: playinverted image is disabled because the user hasn't chosen a file yet. When the user choses a file, it becomes enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. Here is the answer I came up with, inspired by A-Live's answer.

First I had to set the button as enabled, then set the image, and then disable the button again all within the same method. This has fixed my problem.

```
[self.playButton setEnabled:YES];
[self.playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playinverted"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.playButton setEnabled:NO];
```

Comment: Do you always disable the buttons with inverted images (the code looks like you do) ? In this case the solution with `UIControlStateDisabled` would be better as you'd have to set the images only once.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I set it for UIControlStateDisabled, the button doesn't have a disabled state. It isn't light, with a low alpha, for instance. If I do it the way above, the app remembers to disable the button and give it a lightened state.

Answer (score 0):

try using :

```
theButton.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = false
```

this will use your custom image instead of the default dimming.